# Yup 1.x: how to validate against the schema of a specific field

Tags: typescript, validation, yup

in older versions of yup, we were able to use something like this directly

```
const fieldValidator = Yup.reach(yupSchema, fieldName); //RELEVANT
if (fieldValidator === undefined) {
  throw new Error(`Field ${fieldName} is not defined in the schema.`);
}
await fieldValidator.validate(value, { strict: true });
```

however, the type returned by reach has changed in the 1.x line, and I'm not sure how it's intended to be used

https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/443093320217b8b7df4ac077c7882901fcc819fa/src/util/reach.ts#L74

```
function reach<P extends string, S extends ISchema<any>>(
  obj: S,
  path: P,
  value?: any,
  context?: any,
):
  | Reference<Get<InferType<S>, P>>
  | ISchema<Get<InferType<S>, P>, S['__context']> {
  return getIn(obj, path, value, context).schema as any;
}
```

so now reach can return a Reference or an ISchema. in the case of an ISchema, we can call validate like we used to, and we are golden. I'm just not sure how a reference should be handled in this case...any pointers? I guess I could just throw and say that references aren't allowed, but I'm wondering if there's some cleaner way